# How to know login and logout details of a user in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

Please suggest me the solution. How to find a user login and logout details.

Comment: I am using Sharepoint 2013 on premises.

Comment: Please elaborate more

Answer (score 2):

This would require custom implementation using SSOM.  You can try [SPAudit class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms458658(v=office.15).aspx)

Or

You can use cookie to be a flag for checking whether there is a user logged in.

After the page is loaded, if the cookie is null, it suggests that there is a user logged in on the site, then you can get this user’s information using JavaScript Object Model and store the information into a custom list.